# HTMLUListElement has no method appendChild?

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs

I am using PrototypeJS and have selected a `HTMLUListElement` node.

I cannot seem to append it or anything. I always get `HTMLUListElement` has no method appendChild.

I do

```
rotator.obj_rotator.select('ul.slide-navigation')
```

then

```
var li = new Element('li');
rotator.settings.navigatorlis.insert(li);
```

Rotator is the class and settings is a hash within that class. How am I supposed to append this? What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `Element` needed an index:

```
var li = new Element('li', {index:i});
```